# How to retrieve NSUserDefaults and push second View after installition

Tags: ipad, ios5, nsuserdefaults, login-control

I have a Web based application which fetches almost all of its data from my server. In my login view i enter some user informations and create a GET request to server(i do these things in a method called `loginMethod`), if the entered values match with ones in database in response i return some detail data, save user informations to `NSUserDefaults` and push a new viewcontroller(my main view). Anything is ok till here but i want to add a control to my AppDelegate class, if there is no data in defaults(mean, if it is the first time) i want to display login view controller, if there is saved data i want to display main menu. I tried a few ways but failed all the time. Here is my code:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
//uName, serve1r and pasword are my user defaults
        NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         uName   = [defaults objectForKey:@"kUsername1"];
         serve1r = [defaults objectForKey:@"kServer1"];
         pasword = [defaults objectForKey:@"kPassword1"];
        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
        if([uName isEqualToString:@""]){
            //BNT_DetailViewController is my login class
         detailViewController1 = [[[BNT_DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BNT_DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController1] autorelease];
            self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;}
        else{
            //controller is an instance of MainMenu class
            controller = [[[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller] autorelease];
            self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

**EDIT** It doesn't crash but it displays a black screen. There is no problem with saving the values

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? Crash?

Comment: @Saphrosit no it displays just a blank&black screen

Answer (score -1):

considers that the method objectForKey if the value does not exist returns nil and not empty strigna, then hypothetically arriveresti not ever check the first condition.